# Social graph: Pandas dataframe to Networkx graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graphviz

I have a dataset that contains a user and each friend they have. The format is similar to the below where there is a `user_id` field and `friend_id` field containing the corresponding IDs of each friend.

```
user_id | friend_id
   A          B
   A          C
   B          A
   B          G
```

I'm aiming to get an undirected graph showing an edge between each user and every friend they have like below.

```
A - B - G
|
C
```

I'm having difficulty finding out how to link `pandas` to `networkx` or `graphviz` and other resources that expand on creating a social graph from tabular data.

Comment: Why do you need to do it directly from pandas? you can iterate over the records and create the relevant nodes and edges.

Comment: shhh @black hasn't finished their test yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example here is a way to show an undirected network graph using `networkx`, `pandas`, and `matplotlib`.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# store pairs to a list of tuples
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

# set up a graph and show it
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(tuples)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.xticks([], [])
plt.yticks([], [])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: was able to clean up your answer for my use case. Had to look through the `networkX` docs a bit more and get what I wanted. Thanks for your help in getting the starter code together.